# Spam post types in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to add action 'spam' to my post type actions but when clicking on the link I'm getting this error 'The link you followed has expired.'. Followed some instructions such as increasing max_execution_time nothing it's working as expected. Bellow you have the code.

```
function wpc_remove_add_row_actions( $actions, $post ){
   if( $post->post_type === 'cpost' ){ 
      $url = admin_url( 'edit.php?post=' . $post->ID );
      $spam_link = wp_nonce_url(add_query_arg( array( 'action' => 'spam' ), $url ), 'cpost');
      $actions['spam'] = '<a href="'.$spam_link.'">Spam</a>';
    }   
    return $actions;  
}  
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'wpc_remove_add_row_actions', 10, 2 );
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in regards you Wordpress Nonce validation not your PHP settings. Also, in your case, you should be calling the `post.php` page instead `edit.php` page, and have to declare your custom post action request (spam) to handle the resquest using `add_action( "post_action_{$action}", 'my_custom_action', 10, 1 );`, see docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_action_action/

On `my_custom_action()` function you should verify the nonce you have declared on your `post_row_actions` filter using the Wordpress `check_admin_referer()` function.

So, let's wrap everything up:

First update the `edit.php` to `post.php`:

```
function wpc_remove_add_row_actions( $actions, $post ){
  if( $post->post_type === 'cpost' ){ 
      $url = admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $post->ID );
      $spam_link = wp_nonce_url(add_query_arg( array( 'action' => 'spam' ), $url ), 'cpost');
      $actions['spam'] = '<a href="'.$spam_link.'">Spam</a>';
    }   
    return $actions;  
}  
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'wpc_remove_add_row_actions', 10, 2 );
```

By the Wordpress docs the second parameter of `wp_nonce_url()` is the 'Nonce action name'. See docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_url/

> wp_nonce_url(add_query_arg( array( 'action' => 'spam' ), $url ),
>   'cpost');

So, your nonce name is `cpost`

Now you just need to setup your custom action handler:

```
// define the post_action_<action> callback 
function my_custom_action_spam( $post_id ) { 
    check_admin_referer('cpost'); //Your nonce name validation
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 
// add the action 
add_action( "post_action_spam", 'my_custom_action_spam', 10, 1 );
```